# Is there a method to measure the similarity between undirected graph vertices?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matrix-calculus, network

I'm doing some research on `User Identity Resolution`. Assume i can get two undirected graphs of a person, one is the friendship in Twitter of that person, the other is the friendship in Facebook of that person.(For Twitter, i remove the single relation and preserve the mutual relation.).

I want to calculate the similarity between vertices in that undirected graphs to get the possible pairs seem to be same persons.

Let G<sub>T</sub>(n<sub>T</sub>*n<sub>T</sub>) and G<sub>F</sub>(n<sub>F</sub>*n<sub>F</sub>) be two undirected graph. And the result may be a n<sub>F</sub>*n<sub>T</sub> matrix, the each value in the result matrix represent the similarity between vertices in above graphs.

And i found [Measure of Similarity between
Graph Vertices: Applications to
Synonym Extraction and
Web Searching](http://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.blondel/publications/02BV-graph.pdf). When i apply the method that thesis proposed to my data, the result isn't satisfied.

Is there other method to do that? Or other method to process the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "the result isn't satisfied"? Not satisfactory? How good a similarity measure are you after? If all you have is simple graphs with no edge labels (or weights) then I'm not sure how similar two vertices can be...

Comment: what if i have a weights info in graphs?

Comment: Well do you have this info? In any case, the point is that two vertices in a simple unweighted graph can only really be distinguished by the connectivity information in the graph. A really simple example would be just the degree of the vertex - how similar is a person with 3 twitter followers to a person with 3 Facebook friends? What if each of their followers has 3 followers, and each friend has 3 friends? Is that the 'same' person?

Comment: What if the graph is a directed graph? And the weights info must be the communication frequency between two nodes.

Comment: @gilleain There is a seed user in these two graphs. That means : we know the seed user is the same person in these two graphs. Can we start from that node to calculate the others?

Comment: I've no idea! :) What I'm trying to say is that there are many mathematical ways to calculate 'similarity' between two vertices but it's hard to know if any of them really say anything meaningful about two people based on their friends/followers. The more information you have (edge weights, for example) the more likely you can distinguish different people - but I'm not sure that it follows you can identify people this way. A loner with 1 facebook friend seems unlikely to be the same person as a tweeter with 1,000 followers, certainly.

Comment: ...but not all loners with 1 friend are the same person as all tweeters with one follower! Yes, perhaps giving a 'root' to the graph using a known pair of fb/tweeter to start with might help, but there are still many ways to map the two graphs onto each other.

Comment: @gilleain What's `there are still many ways to map the two graphs onto each other` mean ?